# Django: unable to loaddata, UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, seed, loaddata

I'm new to Django, I'm encounter an error during loaddata.

I had completely dump my data in seed_data.json, but when I attempt to loaddata, it came out UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

At first I dump my data into
python manage.py dumpdata > seed_data.json

Then I removed db.sqlite3
rm db.sqlite3

Make migrations
python manage.py migrate

Now I loaddata seed_data.json, it came out error
python manage.py loaddata seed_data.json

error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Seed_data.json
`[{"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Can add log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "add_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Can change log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "change_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Can delete log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "delete_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 4, "fields": {"name": "Can view log entry", "content_type": 1, "codename": "view_logentry"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 5, "fields": {"name": "Can add permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "add_permission"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 6, "fields": {"name": "Can change permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "change_permission"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 7, "fields": {"name": "Can delete permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "delete_permission"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 8, "fields": {"name": "Can view permission", "content_type": 2, "codename": "view_permission"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 9, "fields": {"name": "Can add group", "content_type": 3, "codename": "add_group"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 10, "fields": {"name": "Can change group", "content_type": 3, "codename": "change_group"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 11, "fields": {"name": "Can delete group", "content_type": 3, "codename": "delete_group"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 12, "fields": {"name": "Can view group", "content_type": 3, "codename": "view_group"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 13, "fields": {"name": "Can add user", "content_type": 4, "codename": "add_user"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 14, "fields": {"name": "Can change user", "content_type": 4, "codename": "change_user"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 15, "fields": {"name": "Can delete user", "content_type": 4, "codename": "delete_user"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 16, "fields": {"name": "Can view user", "content_type": 4, "codename": "view_user"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 17, "fields": {"name": "Can add content type", "content_type": 5, "codename": "add_contenttype"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 18, "fields": {"name": "Can change content type", "content_type": 5, "codename": "change_contenttype"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 19, "fields": {"name": "Can delete content type", "content_type": 5, "codename": "delete_contenttype"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 20, "fields": {"name": "Can view content type", "content_type": 5, "codename": "view_contenttype"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 21, "fields": {"name": "Can add session", "content_type": 6, "codename": "add_session"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 22, "fields": {"name": "Can change session", "content_type": 6, "codename": "change_session"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 23, "fields": {"name": "Can delete session", "content_type": 6, "codename": "delete_session"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 24, "fields": {"name": "Can view session", "content_type": 6, "codename": "view_session"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 25, "fields": {"name": "Can add hall", "content_type": 7, "codename": "add_hall"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 26, "fields": {"name": "Can change hall", "content_type": 7, "codename": "change_hall"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 27, "fields": {"name": "Can delete hall", "content_type": 7, "codename": "delete_hall"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 28, "fields": {"name": "Can view hall", "content_type": 7, "codename": "view_hall"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 29, "fields": {"name": "Can add video", "content_type": 8, "codename": "add_video"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 30, "fields": {"name": "Can change video", "content_type": 8, "codename": "change_video"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 31, "fields": {"name": "Can delete video", "content_type": 8, "codename": "delete_video"}}, {"model": "auth.permission", "pk": 32, "fields": {"name": "Can view video", "content_type": 8, "codename": "view_video"}}, {"model": "auth.user", "pk": 1, "fields": {"password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$zPBwS4PpoNrMI3rUkow0fD$IQhuc0iYJ+RgXmfiOp8vuDyCX/L+O1JdS4lyAo0Zi1Y=", "last_login": "2022-07-24T02:56:00.365Z", "is_superuser": true, "username": "lim", "first_name": "", "last_name": "", "email": "", "is_staff": true, "is_active": true, "date_joined": "2022-07-24T02:55:43.312Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": []}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 1, "fields": {"app_label": "admin", "model": "logentry"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 2, "fields": {"app_label": "auth", "model": "permission"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 3, "fields": {"app_label": "auth", "model": "group"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 4, "fields": {"app_label": "auth", "model": "user"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 5, "fields": {"app_label": "contenttypes", "model": "contenttype"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 6, "fields": {"app_label": "sessions", "model": "session"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 7, "fields": {"app_label": "fame", "model": "hall"}}, {"model": "contenttypes.contenttype", "pk": 8, "fields": {"app_label": "fame", "model": "video"}}, {"model": "sessions.session", "pk": "ezpdd3xlkkfxd0gqld5u15j0gxhmht4u", "fields": {"session_data": ".eJxVjEEOwiAQRe_C2pDCANO6dN8zkIEBqRqalHZlvLtt0oVu_3vvv4WnbS1-a2nxE4urUOLyuwWKz1QPwA-q91nGua7LFOShyJM2Oc6cXrfT_Tso1MpeO53NYAGRsIfMBM51kHOXIhpywTJanbQ1kRRGiD3rADtgwkEp7YL4fAHVKjeh:1oFRmi:c99Reivn2NFxVryJZwpDnJ1zopWUPGtF28P0a7Zvw4c", "expire_date": "2022-08-07T02:56:00.418Z"}}, {"model": "fame.hall", "pk": 1, "fields": {"title": "kamsu", "user": 1}}, {"model": "fame.hall", "pk": 2, "fields": {"title": "bird", "user": 1}}, {"model": "fame.hall", "pk": 3, "fields": {"title": "bed", "user": 1}}, {"model": "fame.video", "pk": 1, "fields": {"title": "TAEYONG, JENO, HENDERY, YANGYANG, GISELLE 'ZOO' Stage Video", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IBSemQmno8", "youtube_id": "0IBSemQmno8", "hall": 1}}, {"model": "fame.video", "pk": 2, "fields": {"title": "Revisπo de VΘspera Presencial PC BA", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CobEK7Y7J4w", "youtube_id": "CobEK7Y7J4w", "hall": 2}}, {"model": "fame.video", "pk": 3, "fields": {"title": "ARY News exposed Deputy Speaker Dost Mazari's letter to Chief Secretary Punjab", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9kkehYOkl0", "youtube_id": "Y9kkehYOkl0", "hall": 3}}]`

I have no idea what this error means, and any solution?

Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: Are you running on Windows?  Did you edit this in an editor?  My guess is that your file contains a Unicode byte-order mark (BOM).

Comment: Hi Tim, yes I running in Windows, may i know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @ChaiYonXing there is a solution?

Comment: no solution, I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: copy/paste worked for me...